# How to use any Higher order functions in JavaScript to get the desired output for following code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, higher-order-functions

I have input `string = 'ABCDEFGHI' and N = 3`. Now I want to get output as `'CFIBGAHEJD'` by circularly rotating input string and using `N` value.

Explanation:

```
string = ABCDEFGHI 
O/P = C

string = ABDEFGHI
O/P = CF

string = ABDEGHI
O/P = CFI

string = ABDEGH
O/P = CFIB

.
.
.
string = D
O/P = CFIBGAHEJ

string = ''
O/P = CFIBGAHEJD
```

I write code in JavaScript as below.

```js
function alphabet(string,N){
  string = string.split('');
  newStr = "";
  var count = 0;
  var  i = 0
  while(string.length > 0){
    count++;
    
    if(count === N ){ 
      newStr += string.splice(i,1)
      count = 0;
      i = i-1; 
    }
    if( i === string.length-1){ 
      i = -1; 
    }
    if(string.length === 1){
      newStr += string.splice(0,1)
    }
    i++
  }

console.log(newStr);

}
alphabet("ABCDEFGHIJ",3)
alphabet("ABCDEFGHIJ",12)
alphabet("ABC",5)
```

Now, as a beginner I want to do this using higher-order functions in JavaScript. But i am not able to cracking it. Anyone can help me to get output using those functions. If we can't able use those functions for this type of problem just tell me the reason why we can't.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's literally no reason to use higher-order functions - they take functions as arguments, and that isn't what you need here. If you really wanted to, you could do something like this:

```js
function alphabet(string, numFunc) {
  const N = numFunc();
  string = string.split('');
  newStr = "";
  var count = 0;
  var i = 0
  while (string.length > 0) {
    count++;

    if (count === N) {
      newStr += string.splice(i, 1)
      count = 0;
      i = i - 1;
    }
    if (i === string.length - 1) {
      i = -1;
    }
    if (string.length === 1) {
      newStr += string.splice(0, 1)
    }
    i++
  }

  console.log(newStr);

}
alphabet("ABCDEFGHIJ", () => 3);
alphabet("ABCDEFGHIJ", () => 12);
alphabet("ABC", () => 5);
```

But it's just overcomplicated - your original approach was best.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When I reading about higher order functions in internet they said if you are using loops in JavaScript instead of higher-orders then you are doing something wrong. So that's the reason I wanted to do this in those functions. Anyway thanks for your answer and appreciation.

Comment: Higher-orders are more complicated - a simple `for` loop is perfect for nearly everything. Or look at built-in higher-order functions - `forEach` or `map` for instance. But no, if looping is simpler, use it - I barely *ever* use higher-order functions (I can't remember having a use/need for one).

Comment: @MohanKumarsajjamoka it's not that if you're not using higher order function than it is wrong, it's fine to use normal looping, but using higher order functions is generally preferred way in many cases

Comment: @CodeManiac Thanks for your suggestion. I will remember your point.

Comment: @JackBashford yeah by definition it is, as far as i am understanding OP is looking for use of higher order functions such as `map, reduce...` instead of simple looping that's what his first comment mention here

Comment: However, this function is *considerably* simpler with a looping approach rather than a higher-order function approach - and any such approach would likely be recursive and less performant.